# Paginator numbers in Cake 2

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

when I create links in Cake Paginator with:

```
$this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => '', 'modulus' => 2))
```

I get the result:

1 2 3 4 5 [6] 7 8 9 10

6 - current page

I want result:

1 .. 4 5 [6] 7 8 .. 10

Why option modulus dont working? I think that with modulus =2 result should be that what I want to achieve.

Comment: I think what both of the people who answered were trying to point out, that in your example, you actually are limiting it to two, but your 'first' and 'last' each have 2 next to them as well, so it appears as though you're seeing more than you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the documentation first. Modules is the amount of records shown around the page you're on. [The documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#creating-page-number-links) explains this pretty clearly:

> Uses a modulus to decide how many numbers to show on each side of the
>   current page By default 8

There is even an example for what you want:

```
echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array(
        'first' => 2,
        'last' => 2,
        'modulus' => 2
    )
);
```

Output:

> 1 | 2...5 | 6 | 7...56480 | 56481

Yea I've got a ton of records in that table. ;)

Comment: Removed comment about yours being second - I was mistaken.  But keeping my down-vote for the belittling answer (not to mention complete lack of explanation).  BTW - that's not my answer you revenge-downvoted).

Answer (score 0):

Are you overriding the 'first' and 'last' parameters?

This code should give you what you're after:

```
echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array(
    'separator' => ' ',
    'modulus' => 4,
    'first' => 1,
    'last' => 1
));
```

On my system it gives the following output:

```
1...5 6 7 8 9...13
```